# How long would it take to crack hashed password stored in plain sight?

Tags: hash, password-cracking, credentials, dictionary, argon2

I want to store a password hash in plain sight. If I am using a dictionary to crack an Argon2 hashed password that I am storing in plain sight, how long would it take (assuming my password is reasonably complex)? Further, are there any other attack risks that I am not aware of by storing password hash in plain sight?

Comment: What is the purpose to use password, if you authenticated user by public key?

Comment: The purpose of password is to free up user from having to carry around the private key/signing application (eg, wallet). For example, I want to go to the library and be able to login without needing to set up a wallet and input my secret key into that public computer (or derive it from a long cumbersome mnemonic phrase).

Comment: Do you mean that you want users to enter theirs passwords on PCs that don't belong them? This would be a security disaster. It makes no sense to talk about hashing, Argon2 etc. if the attacker can easily use the same PC as the user. Here are just a few easy ways for the attacker to get access to your users' accounts.

Comment: 1) In a library the attacker can easily see what password has user entered.

Comment: 2) Many users don't really understand what cookies are. They will leave browser with valid cookies. The attacker will get direct access to the account without even knowing the password.

Comment: 3) Even if cookies deleted, the attacker can see files in the browser cache and in the temp directory. There can be sensitive information.

Comment: 4) Depending on security level in the library, the attacker can install a key logger in the OS.

Comment: 5) The attacker can install a malicious browser extension that records user input.

Comment: 6) The attacker can install an own CA certificate and intercept the whole traffic using MITM.

Comment: That's why the question *"How vulnerable to dictionary attack is Argon2d hash ... ?"* makes no sense at all. The attacker does not need to attack the hash. The attacker will use much more easier ways, like the mentioned above.

Comment: Ok, perhaps the library example was poorly formed. I apologize. I won't try to refute any of the above, because you're right. Let me try to rephrase the question for you:

"I want to store a password hash in plain sight. If I am using a dictionary to crack an Argon2 hashed password that I am storing in plain sight, how long will it take? (--assuming my password is reasonably complex). Further, are there any other attack risks that I am not aware of by storing password hash in plain sight?"

Does that formulation of the question make more sense to you? I appreciate your patience.

Comment: The purpose of this site is to be helpful not only to you, but also to as many other users as possible. That's why you rephrase not for me, but for all users. Please add this clarification to the question. And after you add it, the the previous version of the question is not relevant at all.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I am using a dictionary to crack an Argon2 hashed password that I am storing in plain sight, how long will it take? (--assuming my password is reasonably complex).

The success of brute-forcing depends mainly on following factors:

- Password entropy
- Parameters used for Argon2
- Attacker resources

Modern GPUs can compute more than 100 000 000 quick hashes (like SHA-256) per second. Parameters are usually chosen such that hashing takes long enough to slow the attacker down, but still fast enough to be acceptable for normal users. Let say you set parameters so that hashing of single password takes 1s. Thus you make brute-forcing 100 000 000 times slower compared to SHA-256.

Suppose passwords use randomly selected 64 characters. If password length is 10, then there are 64<sup>10</sup> = 2<sup>60</sup> potential passwords. To try all of them the attacker will need 2<sup>60</sup> seconds, which means 2<sup>35</sup> years. If the attacker could afford 1 000 000 000 such powerful GPUs, then it would be needed 100 000 years.

Means, even if password is as short as 10 characters and is generated *randomly*, it can still be unbreakable.

But if passwords were not generated randomly, but were chosen from a dictionary of let say 10 000 often used words, then slightly modified, and the attacker creates 100 modifications for each dictionary word, then there would 1 000 000 password candidates to test. Which means 278 hours, or less than 12 days for a single GPU.

You can similarly calculate the brute-forcing time for other cases, e.g. if only 26 English letters are used, case insensitive. Or if password length is 15 or 20.